# google maps v3 - Add markers after ajax call completes

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to load markers on Google map using ajax call. The ajax call is taking long time but the map is loading before the ajax call is completed. So I don't see markers on the map.

Code given below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var map;
function initialize() {
    var myLatlng;
    var mapOptions;     
    myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng("29.9844", "-95.33389");
    mapOptions = {
                zoom: 12,   
                center: myLatlng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP };

   map = new google.maps.Map(
   document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
 google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function() {
         getRegions( function( result ) {
            alert("getRegions callback return value : " +  result.regionList );
          addMarkersAtRegionCenter(result );
        });
    });
}
</script>
function addMarkersAtRegionCenter(result) {
    var length = result.regionList.length;
     for(var i=0; i<length; i++)
     {
        var image = result.regionList[i].imageIcon;
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(result.regionList[i].centerLatitude,result.regionList[i].centerLongitude),
                  icon: image,
                  map: map
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) { return function() {
                    window.location.href = marker.url;
               }
             })(marker, i));
     }
 }
function getRegions(regions, callbackRegions) {
  $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : 'getRegions.jsp',
        data : {regions: regions},
        dataType: "json",
        success : function(result, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            // invoke the callback function here
               callbackRegions(result);
         },
        error: function (result, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            // invoke the callback function here
               callbackRegions(result);
        }
 });
}
```

I am getting response from the server which i can see in the browser. I am giving the response below:

> {"regionList":[{"centerLongitude":-95.34890747070312,"imageIcon":"../images/untested-icon.png","centerLatitude":29.980682373046875},{"centerLongitude":-95.34890747070312,"imageIcon":"../images/untested-icon.png","centerLatitude":29.988117218017578},{"centerLongitude":-95.33389282226562,"imageIcon":"../images/untested-icon.png","centerLatitude":29.980682373046875},{"centerLongitude":-95.33389282226562,"imageIcon":"../images/untested-icon.png","centerLatitude":29.988117218017578}]}

But I am not able to get that response in the alert message in the above code. Any idea what's the issue here?

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: I am using the ajax call in the following code. google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function() {
   Ajax call in the method.
   getAirportRegions(regions, kpiName, selectedCarrier);
 });

Comment: Please edit your question to include your code with comments where you are stuck.  Please don't put code in comments as its too hard to read

Comment: See my answer below - I updated it based on your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that I can see your code I see a problem with your getRegions function. When you call getRegions your only passing in the callback function.

```
getRegions( function( result ) {
            alert("getRegions callback return value : " +  result.regionList );
          addMarkersAtRegionCenter(result );
        });
```

The problem is that the function is expecting two parameters:

```
function getRegions(regions, callbackRegions)...
```

In your success function your calling callbackRegions but it will be undefined.

1. Create a separate callback function called regionsLoaded:

   ```
   function regionsLoaded(result)
   {
       alert("getRegions callback return value : " +  result );
   }
   ```
2. Change your getRegions function to the following:

   ```
   function getRegions(callbackRegions)...
   ```
3. Then make your call like this:

   ```
   google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function() 
        {
       var regions =  getRegions(regionsLoaded);                       
   });
   ```

Here is a JS fiddle to help you  https://jsfiddle.net/loanburger/ugebw5hb/